# mySQL 3 tables are refered in each one

Tags: mysql, command-line, parent-child, erd

im confuse about this ERD since it is refered in each table. First thing I did, was able to create the tables by altering **EMPLOYEE** table and ADD FOREIGN KEY to the **DEPT_CODE** at the end, as what I understand in the ERD, my question is how do I add or insert value even there's nothing in the parent table? I havent figure it even making the **DEPT_CODE** accept NULL

[image]

Answer that could guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inserting, it does not matter if the parent table has a value or not, as long as the child table has a foreign key, it will work just fine to insert or update data.